# how to get the total number of TODO for all my org-agenda files - orgmode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

i want to have an idea of how much TODO are left in all my org-agenda files.

how can i get the number of TODO in a custom agenda view ?
i cannot believe there is no way to do that in orgmode

is there some code to display that info elsewhere, like in the bottom of a buffer ?

Comment: One way to do it is to generate the global TODO list (`C-c a t` if you have set up the suggested global bindings), go to the end of the buffer with `M->` and look at the line number: it'll be off by 2 (probably - it depends on how many TODO states you have). That's obviously a hacky workaround, but it can be made into a proper function that returns the exact number, *if needed*.

Comment: yup that would be an ephemeral way to have that info, just like using count-match on TODO. but i want a way to have it rendered automatically some here. like in the modline, or in a placeholder. unfortunately i will need monts to learn elisp i guess

Comment: I wrote an [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37724/see-total-number-of-entries-in-global-todo-list/48541#48541) to a similar question. See if that helps.

Comment: hi jagrg, i tried to add your hook to my emacs config and reloaded it with eval-buffer command, but it does not display any more info in my agenda default view. did i missed something ?

Comment: Maybe try using a different face, or change the search string.